# Український відповідник до слова "стартап"

Tags: вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова

Сьогодні досить часто можна почути слово "стартап", що означає: "*нещодавно створена компанія, що володіє обмеженим набором ресурсів та будує свій бізнес на основі інновацій або інноваційних технологій*". Також, на Вікіпедії є такий термін як "стартап-компанія".

На Словотворі відповідником до цього слова пропонують "почин", однак якщо заглянемо в СУМ, то бачимо, що значення у нього трішки інше: "п*очинання, ініціатива*" та "*перші моменти вияву якоїсь дії, стану; початок*". Та й на самому Словотворі у коментарях зазначено, що "*"Почин" більше підходить загалом для слова "старт" в значенні починання якоїсь справи. А для "стартапу" потрібен вужчий термін, можливо, з цим самим коренем*", з чим я також погоджуюся.

Отож, чи є у нашій мові якийсь відповідник до даного слова?